# How do I clear "The unique id is 1" and "FileNotFoundError"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Got stuck while running the code. The file path shown below is the path given to display the output i.e I am renaming it. Now, I am unable to get the output.

```
The unique id is 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\ISRO\S_data\codes\Auto.py", line 390, in <module>
    os.rename("C:\\Users\\finol\\Desktop\\ISRO\\Final Program\\OVERVIEW.OUT", str(uniqueid[a][0])) ##The output file is renames with the uniqueid
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\finol\\Desktop\\ISRO\\Final Program\\OVERVIEW.OUT' -> '1'
'''
And this is the part of the code
```

import os

```
os.rename("C:\\Users\\finol\\Desktop\\ISRO\\Final Program\\OVERVIEW.OUT",
          str(uniqueid[a][0]))  ##The output file is renames with the uniqueid
import shutil

shutil.move(str(uniqueid[a][0]),
            "C:\\Users\\finol\\Desktop\\ISRO\\Final Program\\OUTPUT\\")  ##The output file is moved to a seperate directory
a = a + 1
```

Comment: Did you misspell `final` as `finol`?

Comment: how do you want the file to be renamed? is the file available in the mentioned path

Comment: This question is unclear, and the code needs to be at least partially appended to the post.

Comment: @blhsing Nope.. It is "finol" only

Comment: @Jeril The file is not there in the mentioned path. I am trying to create a path for the output which is been specified.

Comment: ```  import os

    os.rename("C:\\Users\\finol\\Desktop\\ISRO\\Final Program\\OVERVIEW.OUT",
              str(uniqueid[a][0]))  ##The output file is renames with the uniqueid
    import shutil

    shutil.move(str(uniqueid[a][0]),
                "C:\\Users\\finol\\Desktop\\ISRO\\Final Program\\OUTPUT\\")  ##The output file is moved to a seperate directory
    a = a + 1 ``` This is the part of the code@FarhoodET

Comment: can you share the code where you try to create the file and save

Comment: Yes, its been mentioned in the description box. @Jeril

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the input path in raw format by appending an `r` to the string input path in the following format :

```
os.rename(r"C:\\Users\\finol\\Desktop\\ISRO\\Final Program\\OVERVIEW.OUT",
      str(uniqueid[a][0]))
```

I have linux system so I couldn't replicate the problem on my own system, but this should work. You can also change `\\` to `/` to see if it works.

Comment: can you share the directory snapshot as well? Also, try to enter the directory path in single quotes (along with 'r'), or try to rename the directory "Final Program" to another name which does not contain any whitespace in between.